# Bootstrap xs should be "less than 768" so how come it breaks already at 826?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I tried to test this way, and I measured with photoshop. 
My ultimate goal is to make the xs be smaller (for small devices)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid visible-xs" style="border: 1px solid black;">
  <div>HOW COME THIS IS SHOWN AT WIDTH 826px AND NOT AT 768px</div>
  <div>AND HOW CAN I CHANGE THAT TO 480px</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by **break**? The div with text will display when browser size is less than 768px, and your code works as it is supposed to.

Comment: You're example does not display anything over 767px: if you're going to test HTML/CSS use a **browser**, not photoshop.

Comment: Thats what I thought - but it breaks already at 826px - try it out and measure the width at the point it breaks.  This is what I do not understand.

Comment: vanburen so browser width of 826px is actually 767px?  or?

Comment: You still have not explained what _break_ means as far as your example goes. Use this CSS with the example you posted then resize your browser above & below 768px: `@media (min-width:768px){body{background:#add8e6}}@media (max-width:767px){body{background:#e0ffff}}`

Comment: @vanburen - what I want is for some elements to appear and others to disappear when the browser reaches e.g. 480px.   
And you are right about the resolution - I did the myWidth = document.body.clientWidth; myHeight = document.body.clientHeight; and it breaks (or sets the xs to visable) exactly when browser width hits 767px. (learned something new there hehe).  Now my question is - how come the value in the bootstrap thingy is set to 480px for the XS? 
I took a screenshot of the settings
https://db.tt/C0Xaeb9k

Comment: Hmmm if the SM is 768, bootstrap will show the XS when we hit 767.  And the XS = 480 value means nothing.  Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: If you look closer to your screenshot you'll notice that most of those rules are _deprecated_ as of *v3.0.1*: *_Deprecated @screen-xs as of v3.0.1_*. See [Media Queries](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries).

Comment: Ahh yes - I have to remember to check the version number when I look at example code :-D    
(im pretty new at bootstrap)

Comment: The code is working correctly. It is shown up at 768px.